# RouterLink url changes to default url while opening new tab

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

Routerlink url should not change to default url..

When I use  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true }); its working fine.. but I changed to useHash = false, its not working

In html I have used this code:

```
<a routerLink="/applicationredirect" [queryParams]="{appId: recentMenu.applicationId}">{{recentMenu.applicationMasterName}} - {{recentMenu.applicationCode}}</a>
```

Routing page:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
       .....
 {
   path: 'applicationredirect', component: ApplicationRedirectComponent,
 },
  {
path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
   }
  ...
// otherwise redirect to home
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
  ];
const StartupRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: false });
```

When I open in new tab,

First I got,

localhost:4200/applicationredirect?appId=1084518

then it changes to this,

localhost:4200#/home

finally I got this default page

localhost:4200/home#/home

I want (localhost:4200/applicationredirect?appId=1084518) url to be open..

Answer (score 0):

That's a normal behavior. Several points:

- If you want to call routes without the hash, don't provide the second argument  `{ useHash: ... }`
- You didn't declared the `applicationredirect` segment in your router config object, so until you declare it, it will fallback to the `/home` route as you set it to `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }`.
- Remove this if you have it in any module: `{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }` since PathLocationStrategy is [default strategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles)